# How can I modify the prompt of another command?

Tags: completing-read

How can I modify the prompt of another interactive command without copy-pasting too much?
Can I override only the interactive form?

Answer (score 2):

If the interactive form is smaller, I can copy and paste the form, and then call the original function.